# Select certain properties from a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use an array of property names to return a subset of properties from a collection. I'm sure the answer is out on the interwebs, but my vocabulary is too limited to find it.

My collection:

```
[
  {"name": "sam", "age": 25, "height": 125},
  {"name": "jim", "age": 20, "height": 126},
  {"name": "bob", "age": 30, "height": 134}
]
```

My property filter array:

```
["name", "age"]
```

My **goal** is to filter my original collection to look like this:

```
[
  {"name": "sam", "age": 25},
  {"name": "jim", "age": 20},
  {"name": "bob", "age": 30}
]
```

Can someone help me write an efficient function to do this? I've looked through the *lodash* library, but couldn't reason about a simple solution. I have a sinking feeling I'm missing something very simple here...

Comment: you just want to remove the height property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this on modern browsers :

```
   var input = [
     {"name": "sam", "age": 25, "height": 125},
     {"name": "jim", "age": 20, "height": 126},
     {"name": "bob", "age": 30, "height": 134}
   ];
   var filter = ["name", "age"];
   var result = input.map(function(v) {
        var o = {};
        for (var i=0; i<filter.length; i++) o[filter[i]] = v[filter[i]]
        return o;
   });
```

If you want to be compatible with ie8, you need [a shim for map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or to use a for loop instead.

Comment: Genius, I think this is exactly where I was headed. I had a hunch `map` was needed. I'll mark as answer in a minute once I test!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something exists elsewhere on the web that already does this, but you could do this fairly easy as follows:

```
var collection = [
  {"name": "sam", "age": 25, "height": 125},
  {"name": "jim", "age": 20, "height": 126},
  {"name": "bob", "age": 30, "height": 134}
];

var properties = ["name", "age"];

function filterProperties(col, props) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var obj = {};

        for (var k = 0; k < props.length; k++) {
            obj[props[k]] = col[i][props[k]];
        }

        result.push(obj);
    }

    return result;
}

var filtered = filterProperties(collection, properties);
```

Comment: Agreed, I undid the downvote by +1. I hate when people do that.

Comment: It's virtually the same thing as the accepted answer except that instead of using `map()` I wrote out the initial `for`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fast way without using push() or map() and with the fast while -- loop

your vars

```
var a=[
{"name": "sam", "age": 25, "height": 125},
{"name": "jim", "age": 20, "height": 126},
{"name": "bob", "age": 30, "height": 134}
],
b=["name","age"];
```

fast code

```
var c=[],d=a.length,f=b.length;
while(d--){var g=f,e={};while(g--){e[b[g]]=a[d][b[g]]}c[d]=e};
```

c is your new array

OR

here is a function version

```
// a=pplarray b=filterarray (c,d,e,f,g = placeholder)
function filter(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){
c=[];d=a.length;f=b.length;while(d--){g=f;e={};
while(g--){e[b[g]]=a[d][b[g]]}c[d]=e}return c};
var c=filter(a,b);
```

c is your new array